# SQL Inner join on one field when second is null and on second when first is null

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, join, inner-join

OP is completely new to databases and SQL, so this question may be answered somewhere else but I don't quite have the vocabulary to find what I'm looking for; a push in the right direction would be great.

I'm trying to make a view of two tables inner joined.  This is currently how they look:
[image]

and this is how I would like them to look:
[image]

The issue with this is that the view is empty because c4 and c5 can be null values.

I essentially want these two later inner joins on c4 and c5 to happen if one of them has a value.

Just to be thorough:

1. If c4 exists, inner join on it.
2. If c5 exists, inner join on it.
3. If neither exist, don't inner join on it.

Each of these are preceded by the inner joins between UTC and colNum.  By this I mean that the UTC and colNum joins always happen.

I know that sql is a query language, so it does not do computation, but there must be a filter that will allow for this logic to be applied to these two tables.

It is useful to note that if c4 exists, c5 is null and if c5 exists, c4 is null, and that I still want a row (joined based on the previous two inner joins) if both are null.

Again, I don't really know the language surrounding SQL, so my effort to find an answer before asking one was hampered.  If something like this has already been answered, just point me to it.

Comment: `On (t1.c4 is not null and t2.c4 is not null and t1.c4 = t2.c4) or (t1.c5 is not null and t2.c5 is not null and t1.c5 = t2.c5)`

Comment: @GiorgiNakeuri I'll try and work this in. Where should it go in the query? I've only had mixed results directly modifying my query; I normally just use the UI.

Comment: If you have a query, please include it in your question.

Comment: @GordonLinoff I just tried, but for some reason I attempting to edit my post results in an error. I'll keep trying

Comment: @GordonLinoff I keep trying, but for some reason it won't let me edit in a code block...strange.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is a little big statement to do it in comment so I will post it as an answer. If my understanding of the problem is correct then it will be like:

```
select * 
from sizeconditionstable t1
join specalloytable t2
on (t1.c4 is not null and t2.c4 is not null and t1.c4 = t2.c4) or 
   (t1.c5 is not null and t2.c5 is not null and t1.c5 = t2.c5)
```

Edit:

```
select * 
    from sizeconditionstable t1
    join specalloytable t2
    on (t1.utc = t2.utc and t1.colnum = t2.colnum) and
       ((t1.c4 = t2.c4) or (t1.c4 is null and t2.c4 is null)) and
       ((t1.c5 = t2.c5) or (t1.c5 is null and t2.c5 is null))
```

This is the version which will join always on `utc` and `colnum` and also on c4 and c5 if they are filled in both tables.

Comment: There are cases where both c4 and c5 are null.  Does this cover those? It does not seem too, but I'm a complete novice.

Comment: No, this will join 2 rows if and only if both c4 in both tabkes are equal or both c5 are equal. If they are null or one of column is null then this statement will not join...

Comment: In the case that both are null, the inner join will prevent the fields from showing from either table. If "3.If neither exist, don't inner join on it." means you still want the sizeconditionstable record to be selected, you'll need that to be a LEFT OUTER JOIN.

Comment: @JacobProffitt  By number three I mean that the previous two inner joins, between UTC and colNum, should create the row.  Those two joins supersede those between c4 and c5.  Sorry for the confusion.

Comment: It is a little bit confusing. Can you elaborate when you want to join on which columns...

Comment: Yeah, definitely confusing question. I have the assumption that c4 and c5 will match on both tables, even if they're null? If that's not true, then that explodes out unpleasantly. If it *is* true, you can take t1.c4 is null with c5 equality *else* take the c4 equality and you're good. So: "AND ((t1.c4 is null and t1.c5 = t2.c5) or (t1.c4 = t2.c4))"?

Comment: Sure.  The UTC field and the colNum field are never null, and always link up across the whole of the table.  These reduce the set of matching rows between tables from several hundred thousand to around 200.  Once I get these 200 rows I want to connect those rows with matching c4 and c5 values together, creating a view that consists of around 20 rows.  The resulting rows will have a c4 value or a c5 value or niether.

Comment: Does this help? Have I shed light on my issue? or have I obfuscated it?

Comment: @JacobProffitt Yes, c4 and c5 should always match.  t1.c4 == t2.c4 and t1.c5 == t2.c5; but it's important that c4 and c5 can be null. It is also important that t1.UTC == t2.UTC and t1.colNum == t2.colNum; these will never be null.

Comment: If "join specalloytable t2 on t1.UTC = t2.UTC AND t1.colNum = t2.colNum AND ((t1.c4 is null and t1.c5 = t2.c5) or (t1.c4 = t2.c4))" does what you think it should, then yeah, more or less.

Comment: @JacobProffitt  I read that query, and I think the case where both c4 and c5 are null is excluded. Is "join specalloytable t2 on t1.UTC = t2.UTC AND t1.colNum = t2.colNum AND ((t1.c4 is null AND t2.c4 is null AND t1.c5 = t2.c5) or (t1.c5 is null AND t2.c5 is null AND  t1.c4 = t2.c4) or (t1.c4 is null AND t2.c4 is null AND t1.c5 is null AND t2.c5 is null))" feel like it might work? How should that look in actual SQL language?

Comment: I'll try it now.  I did not know you could alias tables like that.  Is that what it's called? then you say "specalloytable t2"?

Comment: Everything is working great! Thank you very much all for your help.  I learned a lot.

Answer (score 1):

I think a UNION ALL query is your best bet here.

```
SELECT field1, field2, field3 
FROM table1 t1
JOIN table2 t2 ON t2.field1 = t1.field1 AND t2.field2 = t2.field2
UNION ALL
SELECT field1, field2, field3 
FROM table1 t1
JOIN table2 t2 ON t2.field1 = t1.field1 AND t2.field3 = t2.field3
```

In this case, if field 2 is null and field 3 is not, then there are no results from the first query but the second one brings in the results

Comment: I'll have to look into this.  will this accept null values? that seems to be the crux of my problem.

Answer (score 1):

coalesce(column1, column2, '') will work, however, it isn't cheap so if you are joining two large tables you would be better off with a different approach.

Comment: I'll take a look at coalesce.  Why do you think it is possibly appropriate?

Answer (score 0):

I re-read your request.  A union query is the appropriate solution.  Something along these lines should work well.

```
select  *

from
    (
        select
            t1.primaryKey,
            t2.foreignKey
        from
            table1 t1 inner join table2 t2 on t1.c1 = t2.c1

        union

        select
            t1.primaryKey,
            t2.foreignKey
        from
            table1 t1 inner join table2 t2 on t1.c2 = t2.c2
    ) x inner join table1 t1 on x.primaryKey = t1.primaryKey
    inner join table2 t2 on x.foreignKey
```